# Are there any git clients that run in the browser?

Tags: node.js, git, github

### Background Info

I do most of my Node.js development on a Chromebook and I'm genuinely happy with my workflow. I use [code-server](https://github.com/cdr/code-server) and [node-red](https://nodered.org/) which run locally in the browser.

These work flawlessly, but I'm limited to saving my work through the [git cli](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-The-Command-Line). I've been searching for a [git desktop client](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis/) that runs in the browser but I haven't come across anything.

### My Question

Is it possible to run [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) or [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) in the browser?
If not, are there any projects attempting this?

Comment: Ungit is my favourite.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question a bit, but gitpod.io may help you.